# Disable Automatic Extraction in String Catalog

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, localization, string-catalog

Is there a way to disable automatic extraction when using String Catalog?

The following code block invokes an initializer with `LocalizedStringKey` and not with `StringProtocol`.

```swift
Text("Hello World!")
```

`Text` has a workaround for this in a form of `init(verbatim:)`. But the same functionality doesn't exist for other UI elements—`Button`, `TextField`, etc.

I was looking for more global solution. But using `String("Hello World!")` or `"Hello World!".toString` everywhere seems excessive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do so by updating the following build settings in your target:

- Localized String SwiftUI Support (`LOCALIZED_STRING_SWIFTUI_SUPPORT`): `NO`
- Use Compiler to Extract Swift Strings (`SWIFT_EMIT_LOC_STRINGS`): `NO`